# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request using TIdHTTP

Tags: post, azure, https

I have this code to get access token from the Microsoft Azure DataMarket that produces the error EIdHTTPProtocolException `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`:

```
procedure TADTranslator.GetAccessToken();
var
  HTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  ParamList: TStringList;

  Result: String;
begin
  ParamList := TStringList.Create;
  HTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP1);
    HTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
    //Result := HTTP1.Post('https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13', ParamList);
    Result := HTTP1.Get('https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13');

    FLangAccessToken := Result;
  finally
    HTTP1.Free;
    ParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a curl request to the above url returns 400  Bad request as well. So I think you need to check the documentation on what parameters is required

Comment: "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"ACS90007: Request method not allowed.\r\nTrace ID: f3c2120d-fa7b-4061-8ec9-32046f3631ef\r\nCorrelation ID: 95007af0-05df-4d0f-b0cc-993290de74ee\r\nTimestamp: 2014-11-25 20:10:07Z"}" Looks like the GET request is not supported

Comment: Yeah I guess its all about parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem, you will get this error whenever your parameters are wrong. Very unclear for trouble shooting. I don't know if it is Microsoft's fault or HTTP issues. I was hoping for more clear message, something like "Authentication failed".